# Systemd hangs in Xen Dom0 immediately after switch_root in boot process

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, xen, init

I've been trying to set up Xen to work with UEFI and my Arch Linux install ([3.18.2](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/linux/)) as a Dom0 but have been unable to boot. Of note is the fact that it will boot completely fine otherwise, just not under Xen.

Specifically, my computer freezes completely and I have to hard reset it with no relevant error messages appearing as far as I can tell. After much effort (and discovering `debug=postmount`) I found that it's freezing right after `systemd` is being invoked by `switch_root`.

The real problem is that I have been unable to get systemd to spit out any logs or information before the computer freezes up. I've tried various kernel as well as systemd specific logging options, but right after I exit that post-mount shell I get maybe half a blink of the cursor, with no logs, before the screen freezes.

My current setup is [gummiboot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/gummiboot) launching the Xen EFI using two small config files, included below in case they are relevant:

`$esp/loader/conf/xen.conf`:

```
title   Xen
efi     xen-4.5.0.efi
```

`$esp/xen.cfg` (same directory as `xen-4.5.0.efi`):

```
[global]
default=xen

[xen]
options=console=none dom0_mem=2048M,max=2048M dom0_max_vcpus=1 loglvl=all noreboot
kernel=vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/sda3 rw systemd.unit=emergency.service systemd.log_level=debug
ramdisk=initramfs-linux.img
```

Things to note:

- Tried this with the AUR Xen 4.4.1-3 package as well as downloading and compiling Xen 4.5.0 from source, but both versions freeze at the same point in the boot process.
- I did have to recompile binutils for `x86_64-pep` support in order to generate the EFI but only replaced that. I wouldn't need to replace GCC as well would I? Also note that the [Arch wiki page for Xen](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xen) mentions needing a downgraded version of binutils but both it and the up-to-date version of both fail to boot the same way.
- I tried enabling/disabling all of the xen-related systemd.services as well, but since it looks like systemd is crashing before it loads any services at all.
- Unfortunately neither `systemd.crash_shell=true` nor `systemd.unit=emergency.service` can manage to drop me into a shell after systemd is invoked.
- `init=/bin/sh` works fine as far as I can tell, so its definitely `systemd` and not `switch_root` itself that is the issue.
- Running systemd from the shell (via `init=/bin/sh` and `exec /usr/lib/systemd/systemd`) crashes the same way, and doing `systemd --system --test --log-level=debug` doesn't seem to freak out too much. That is to say, it will output that it knows its in Xen virtualization and in a x86_64 system but doesn't output anything more than like 5 lines total. It then fails the test with [some errors](https://github.com/flonatel/MetaInit/issues/1) related to ironically...not having systemd running yet.

I'm really hoping (and kindof dreading) that there's some simple kernel parameter or Xen Dom0 option that I need to pass to fix this, but any insight or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: So, what are the last two "complaints"? If these are complaints from systemd, and it hangs shortly after, then they possibly contain something valuable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in my case ended up being solved by passing the `no-efi-rs` (no EFI runtime services) flag to the Xen boot options in `xen.cfg`.

If your boot process can get to the `/sbin/init` stage, below is a useful config for Xen:

```
[global]
default=xen

[xen]
options=loglvl=all guest_loglvl=all conring_size=10M console_to_ring=true noreboot
kernel=vmlinuz-linux root=/dev/whatever rw init=/bin/sh log_buf_len=10M loglevel=9 
ramdisk=initramfs-linux.img
```

Once you drop into the shell, you can run

```
# mount xenfs so that the next command actually works
mount -t xenfs xenfs /proc/xen
# display the Xen log, pipe it to a file if you want to save it for later
xl dmesg
```